# How implement an objective-C /swift module to allows an ios application, which sends command to BLE peripheral, execute even in background(offscreen)

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, native, background-process, off-screen

I want to create an application which interacts with my BLE peripheral device even in the background when the screen is off as well. Is there any native implementation to do so, with objC or swift? Can anyone help me with this. I've tried many npm modules but they didn't work. So I'm now trying to implement it natively. I'm new to the objC & swift.
I tried to find documentations, tutorial. But there was none.

I tried some npm modules, but all of them were stopped after a short time when a user leaves the screen.

Comment: Although old [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) is still a very good document on the concepts of background processing with  Core Bluetooth

Comment: I'd consider breaking this question into two different ideas.

1. Is there a native implementation for working with BLE peripherals.
2. When working with BLE, how do I keep these interactions continous when the app is backgrounded.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you help me with both parts, Cause I'm new to this domain.
1. Is there a native implementation for working with BLE peripherals.
2. When working with BLE, how do I keep these interactions continous when the app is backgrounded